# How to use linkedin API using sencha touch

Tags: oauth, sencha-touch-2.1, linkedin-jsapi

I want to integrate login using linkedin API, How can we using linkedin Oauth using sencha touch 2.1.1 ?

Answer (score 1):

The step by step procedure on how to login to LinkedIn is detailed here:-
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/sign-linkedin

From that documentation - you should be able to login using any JavaScript based program - including Sencha Touch.